# Как сделать параллакс показа текста в css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

**Нужно создать такой параллакс эффект**
Не могу понять как создать такой параллакс. Нужно чтобы при скроле проявлялся текст.

---

[image: Не могу понять как создать такой параллакс эфект]

Comment: Слой с текстом внутри, а слой круга - `border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden;`. Параллакс обычный.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar: а если текст на всю ширину экрана, то в каждом кружке текст подгонять? Как я понимаю, здесь просто пример с коротким словом, которое в кружке умещается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решить задачу можно с помощью анимации маски SVG.

1. Нижний слой будет красный прямоугольник с текстом.
2. Верхний слой будет фиолетовый прямоугольник, к которому применена маска с набором окружностей, у которых `fill="black"`  При закраске чёрным цветом маска прорезает верхний слой и становится виден нижний красный слой сквозь эти отверстия.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" >   
        <!-- Маска -->
   <mask id="msk">
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>       
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS</text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  />  
 
</svg>
```

**Теперь можно сделать параллакс**

Для этого нужно просто двигать маску:

*#1. Горизонтальный параллакс*

Начало анимации после клика

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
   <mask id="msk">
   <g>
    <rect  width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>   
         <!-- Анимация движения маски -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="4s"
        values="0 0;400 0"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive" />  
    </g>      
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS</text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  >
        
       </rect>    
         
</svg>
```

*#2. Вертикальный параллаксм*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
   <mask id="msk">
   <g>
    <rect  width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>   
         <!-- Анимация движения маски -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="4s"
        values="0 0;0 100"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive" />  
    </g>      
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS</text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  >
        
       </rect>    
         
</svg>
```

*#3. Вертикальный параллакс с возвратом*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
   <mask id="msk">
   <g>
    <rect  width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>   
         <!-- Анимация движения маски -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="4s"
        values="0 0;0 100;0 100;0 0;0 0"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        restart="whenNotActive" />  
    </g>      
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS</text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  >
        
       </rect>    
         
</svg>
```

### Update

**Анимация движения текста**

В этих примерах маска неподвижна, двигается сам текст

*#1. По горизонтали*

```
<!-- Анимация движения текста -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="6s"
        values="0 0;300 0;0 0"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive" />
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
   <mask id="msk">
  
    <rect  width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>   
              
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS
     <!-- Анимация движения текста -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="6s"
        values="0 0;300 0;0 0"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive" />  
    </text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  >
        
       </rect>    
         
</svg>
```

*#2. По вертикали*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="400" height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
   <mask id="msk">
  
    <rect  width="400" height="100" fill="white" /> 
     <g fill="black">      
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="30"  /> 
        <circle cx="100" cy="90" r="30"  /> 
         <circle cx="200" cy="-25" r="80"  /> 
            <circle cx="320" cy="50" r="32"  /> 
               <circle cx="405" cy="90" r="30" /> 
        </g>   
              
    </mask>  
        <!-- Красный фон с текстом -->
    <rect width="400" height="100" fill="#FE5F55" />    
    <text x="200" y="65" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48px" font-weight="700" fill="white">BIOS
     <!-- Анимация движения текста по вертикали -->
      <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="4s"
        values="0 0;0 50;0 -30"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive" />  
    </text>
              <!-- Синий маскирующий прямоугольник -->
      <rect width="400" height="100" mask="url(#msk)" fill="#8E5DF8"  >
        
       </rect>    
         
</svg>
```

Comment: Оромное спасибо! Вышло очень красиво. Немного дороботал ваш код с использованием простенького паралакса JS. Благодарю!

Comment: @MineWeeper и я благодарю Вас за  интересный вопрос. Надеюсь увидеть ешё ваши новые вопросы. Только есть одна просьба, - при создании следующего вопроса, давать более четкие однозначные формулировки, чтобы не приходилось делать несколько вариантов ответа, как здесь

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Как всегда - Выше всяких похвал )